# Firing a "shot" in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I need to fire a "shot" from a static `SKSpriteNode` towards another dynamic node. I've created a shot as a sprite node as the shot and moved it to by `SKAction` to the main sprite node, like so:

```
let node = info["node"] as SKSpriteNode // The static node

let shot = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSize(width:node.frame.width / 3, height: node.frame.height / 1.2))
shot.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: shot.frame)
shot.position = node.position

shot.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = shotMask
shot.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = spriteMask
shot.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
shot.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

self.addChild(shot)

shot.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(sprite.position, duration: 1.0))
```

My problem is that the shot stops after it reaches the point. Is there a way to make the shot continue moving in it's direction, or is there another way of doing what I need? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a SKAction to move the shot. Instead change the shot's position by directly modifying it's position.

```
shot.position = CGPointMake(shot.position.x+1, shot.position.y);
```

Run the above in your update method. To speed up the shot, change the +1 to whatever value you need. Obviously you will need to remove the shot node from parent once it leaves the screen, hits the target, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to calculate the vector from the shot's origin to it's destination. Then extend the vector until the shot will be off screen, possibly by finding the unit vector (a vector of length 1) and multiplying it by 3000 or so. As you have a definite endpoint now, you could still use an SKAction.